# Check the stable Internet

Tags: java, android, android-wifi, wifimanager

My application uses the getInet4AddressByName () method. It needs the Internet turned on. To check the Wi-Fi status, I use the BroadcastReceiver receiver. But a stable Internet appears after some time after turning on Wi-Fi and the method does not have time to work correctly `getInet4AddressByName()` returns an error. How can I track the presence of a stable Internet connection rather than the wi-fi connection? Thanks.

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
 WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
 if (wifi.isWifiEnabled()) {
   tv.setText("You are connected");
 } else {
   tv.setText("You are NOT connected");
 }
}
};
```

Comment: I _think_ what you want is `ConnectivityManager`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two method :

Google recommends this code block for checking internet connection. Because the device may have not internet connection even if it is connected to WiFi.
1 - for check connection :

```
 private boolean isNetworkConnected() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    return cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null;
}
```

2 - for check internet :

```
  public boolean internetIsConnected() {
    try {
        String command = "ping -c 1 google.com";
        return (Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command).waitFor() == 0);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Add permissions to manifest :

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```